# where the installed programs are actually stored?

Tags: linux, windows, file-location

I have a confusion always , whether installed programs are stored in `hard disk` or in `RAM` ?

Can anyone explain me ?

Comment: `/usr/share/applications/` (the shortcuts) and `/usr/bin` the executables on linux. on windows, depends on the program. all installed software is stored in HD.

Comment: -1: The downvote criteria is: "This question **does not show any research effort**; it is unclear or not useful".  This is easily answerable with research.  Generally, people come here after researching something and have trouble along the way.  The complaint around here is often "we aren't a script writing service" the same is true for "a research service".  Though most folks are happy to help if you have *done some leg work yourself up front*.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_computer_hardware - see here for details for what different components in a computer system are for.

Answer (score 2):

1) as an answer:

The programs are stored on the disk (or other permanent storage. It does not need to be a disk, it can be on a network or any other place such as a ROM).

When you start a program the parts of it which are needed are loaded into the main memory (the RAM). This does not even need to be the whole program, just the pages needed at the time.

And technically the programs do not even need to be in memory. E.g. at boot time a program called the BIOS is executed with the CPU's cache as storage. One of the first things it does it to configure the memory controller so that it has access to main memory. For more information about this exotic usage see the `coreboot` BIOS program which was explained nicely at [FOSDEM 2010](http://www.coreboot.org/FOSDEM_2010)

2) Welcome to [SU]. This is a site for problems and practical answers. Your question does not seem to match this.

Answer (score 0):

They are stored on the `Harddisk`. If you use them, they will be loaded in the `RAM`.

Path in Windows: `C:/Programm Files`
Linux: `/usr/share/applications/`

Comment: I used to watch some of the installed files are going to '/usr/lib' on linux

Comment: Yes. The executables are actually stored there.

Comment: Then what files are stored in /usr/share/applications/ . Even some files goes to /etc directory . can you please give the explanation what files will go to what directories ?

Comment: Actually the shortcuts of the applications.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, computer programs (including the computer operating system) and stored for the long term on a persistent storage media, such as a magnetic hard drive, flash memory device, magnetic tape, or magnetic floppy disk.

This storage media is usually formatted using one of a variety of file systems, that provide for a logical way to keep the binary representations of these files (the 1's and 0's) in a retrievable format.

The files on contained within this file system are generally located in some sort of hierarchical directory tree structure so that files can be easily located and logically grouped together.

On a Windows system, the application's executable files are generally kept (by default) in `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)`, but this could be changed by the user at install time. Programs may also store information in `C:\ProgramData` (Windows 7) and may also store information in one of the profile folders under `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData`, but this varies based on the implementation by the software vendor.

Linux systems generally follow the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) on where the application, once installed, places files. This, however, depends greatly on whether the developer of the software follows these conventions and whether or not the end user made modifications to the installation process to change where these files are to be located.

Once executed, the installed programs generally execute operations in RAM, though they still exist on the long term storage medium unless otherwise removed.

All this information can be easily Googled, really.